# Lost, trying to connect Intel Edison SPI to ADC using the intel XDC and node

Tags: intel-xdk, spi, adc, intel-edison

I am using the intel XDK for the first time and I am trying to get a reading from this SPI ADC ADS7951SRGER 12 Bit Analog to Digital Converter 8 Input 1 SAR 24-VQFN (4x4) http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads7950.pdf

its connected like so

```
SPI_2_RXD -> MISO
SPI_2_TXD -> MOSI
SPI_2_CLK -> SCLK
SPI_2_FS0 -> ADC_CS
```

I have never used SPI before, I am very lost.  I've been searching for 24 hours now and I'm not much closer to understanding what I'm supposed to do here.

here is the current hail mary code I'm trying. all I get back is ffffffff

```
var x = new m.Spi(0);
x.bitPerWord=12;
x.frequency = 20;


var buf = new Buffer(4);
buf[0] = char('0x0b');
buf[1] = char('0x11');
buf[2] = char('0x11');
buf[3] = char('0x11');
var buf2 = x.write(buf);


console.log("Sent: " + buf.toString('hex') + ". Received: " + buf2.toString('hex'));
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try `'\x0b'` instead of `char('0x0b')`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried '\x0b' it didn't change the response

Comment: Can you show the definition of the `char` function?

Comment: function char(x) { 
     return parseInt(x, 16); 
    }

Comment: Well, you don't need that whole dance. you can just write `0x0b` and `0x11`. Also, do you have any error or anything?

Comment: no errors. the 0x11 is just something that i saw someone else used for a different adc.  I'm figuring I'm missing a command or something.  but I really have no clue and i'm not finding a whole lot of documentation that I understand

Comment: I'm now using this code for the send and getting a return of 00000000
    var buf = new Buffer(4);
    buf[0] = '\x0b';
    buf[1] = '\x00';
    buf[2] = '\x00';
    buf[3] = '\x00';

Comment: The last code you've sent is sorta expected, since `\x00` is `0`. What happens when you do `'\x11'`?

Comment: Same thing. return of 00000000

Comment: This is so strange. Something is missing.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that I'm probably missing something with the FS0->Cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to pull the CS (SPI_2_FS0 -> ADC_CS) manually, pulling low before each write/read then high again.

Comment: Which is strange. The driver has to do this for you. But looking to the older  kernel my eyes are in tears. Try to play with upstream kernel. (I have ADC enabling for Edison Arduino in my TODO list, but SPI there works in PIO mode nicely)

Comment: I'm just happy it works. I've had no problems with it